# How is it possible that a block's parameter becomes callable in the example below?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have been playing with ruby recently and understand some basics about passing a block
to a method and how to yield values back to the block etc, but I came across the following
code in Rspec:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
end
```

Now this looks very weired and interesting to me at the same time, but I don't fully understand it.
How is it possible to pass 'config' to configuration and at the same time it becomes a callable object
within the block as 'config.use_transactional_fixtures....'

Could someone please help me with a basic implementation that can be called as in the example above, and is there a name for this technique? I will carry on the quest to figure this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of a class that has a configuration object and a configure method:

```
class ConfigObject
  attr_accessor :some_configuration_variable, :some_option

  def initialize
    # set default values in initialize
    @some_configuration_variable = false
    @some_option = :default
  end
end

class MyClass

  # open the metaclass (access to the MyClass object instance)
  class << self
    def configure
      yield configuration_object
    end

    # return the configuration object, or initialize it if it doesn't yet exist.
    def configuration_object
      @configuration_object ||= ConfigObject.new
    end
  end
end
```

Since the class instance MyClass is a singleton object, only one configuration object will ever exist. Instances of `MyClass` can access the object as `MyClass.new.class.configuration_object`. Or, for a more flexible approach, you can define an accessor to the config object and forward messages to it:

```
require 'forwardable'

class MyClass
  extend Forwardable

  def_delegators :configuration_object, :some_configuration_variable, :some_option

  def configuration_object
    MyClass.configuration_object
  end
end

MyClass.configure do |config|
  config.some_configuration_variable = true
  config.some_option = :option_a
end

instance = MyClass.new
instance.some_configuration_variable #=> true
instance.some_option #=> :option_a
```

Comment: I originally thought of 'config' as an argument being passed to a method instead of value yielded by the configure method, plus I didn't assume you could yield an instance, which is now clearly obvious! looking forward to using this technique in Ruby soon! Thanks for your example Zach.

Answer (score 1):

What happens behinds the scenes is the following:

- The method [`Rspec.configure`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/v2.14.7/lib/rspec/core.rb#L119) is a method that expects a block.
- When you call that method, it calls your block (via `yield`) passing in parameter.
- The parameter passed in is basically a [configuration object](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/v2.14.7/lib/rspec/core.rb#L102) which is an instance of [`RSpec::Core::Configuration`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/v2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb#L31)
- The configuration object, basically has accessor methods for all the available configuration options.

Comment: This now makes perfect sense, thanks for the link to Rspec core, it is nice to see how they implemented it. Was confusing at first, but now I am looking forward to using it soon. I also noticed this is used within rails form_for helper, I am sure I will find it alot within Ruby as I learn more. Mystery demystified! Thank you Nikos

Answer (score 0):

Well, blocks are (for me) one of the toughest things in Ruby, but they are also very powerful when you fully understand how they work.

Let's take the most common function which uses blocks, `each`:

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].each do |value|
  # do something with value
end
```

This is equivalent to `['a', 'b', 'c'].each(&Proc.new{ |v| print v })`, where `&` is the syntax for passing an object to a function marking it as *the block callable via `yield`* (more on `yield` later). So a block is just a `Proc` instance (an anonymous function), thus an object, like everything else in Ruby.

This is a basic implementation of `each` for arrays (it doesn't cover the case when you don't pass a block to it, since it isn't interesting for us, at the moment):

```
def each(array)
  i = 0
  while i < array.size
    yield array[i]
    i += 1
  end
  array
end

each( ['a', 'b', 'c'] ) { |v| print v } #=> prints abc , returns array
```

The key here is `yield`: the block (`{ |v| print v }`), as we said, is a `Proc` instance, which you usually use it passing it to other functions, which usually **execute it calling it with `yield [args]`**. You are not forced to execute it, and you can even have a block reference if declared as argument, and use it as you wish:

```
def puts_block(&block)
  puts block
end

puts_block { |v| } #=> #<Proc:0x007f16092b7660@(irb):15>
```

---

So, `RSpec.configure` is probably implemented like this:

```
class RSpec
  def self.configure
    @config ||= Config.new
    block_given? ? yield @config : @config
  end
end
```

`block_given?` allows to know whether a function is called passing a block to it or not; in this way calling `Rspec.configure` just returns the `@config` object, while `RSpec.configure { |c| ... }` passes the `@config` object to the block you are passing to `RSpec.configure`.

Even more info about Ruby blocks on [Google](https://www.google.com/?q=ruby+blocks#q=ruby+blocks) :P